# How to properly initialize custom class instance with parameterized configuration in top-level?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

How can I use these `defineString()`, `defineInt`, ... in top-level custom class constructor?

`defineString()` returns `StringParam` which has `value()`method.
I want to use parameterized configuration to initialize my custom class instance in top-level.

```js
import {defineString, projectID} from "firebase-functions/params";

const cloudTasksUtil = new CloudTasksUtil(
    defineString("TASKS_QUEUE_NAME").value(),
    defineString("MY_TASKS_LOCATION").value(),
    defineString("G_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL").value(),
    projectID.value(),
);
```

If I use `.value()` method as above, it keeps warning that is is mistake and I should use StringParam itself.
I think I should use StringParam because the instance is initialized before the cloud functions.

I couldn't find any resources related this issue.

**EDIT)**
When I run `firebase functions:shell`, it shows below.

```
✔  functions: Using node@18 from host.
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env, .env.local.
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"params.TASKS_QUEUE_NAME.value() invoked during function deployment, instead of during runtime."}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"This is usually a mistake. In configs, use Params directly without calling .value()."}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"example: { memory: memoryParam } not { memory: memoryParam.value() }"}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"params.MY_TASKS_LOCATION.value() invoked during function deployment, instead of during runtime."}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"This is usually a mistake. In configs, use Params directly without calling .value()."}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"example: { memory: memoryParam } not { memory: memoryParam.value() }"}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"params.G_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL.value() invoked during function deployment, instead of during runtime."}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"This is usually a mistake. In configs, use Params directly without calling .value()."}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"example: { memory: memoryParam } not { memory: memoryParam.value() }"}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"params.PROJECT_ID.value() invoked during function deployment, instead of during runtime."}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"This is usually a mistake. In configs, use Params directly without calling .value()."}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"example: { memory: memoryParam } not { memory: memoryParam.value() }"}
i  functions: Loaded functions: helloWorld, reserveSeat, startTimer, countSeatChange
i  functions: Connected to running firestore emulator at 127.0.0.1:8080, calls to this service will affect the emulator
i  functions: Connected to running database emulator at 127.0.0.1:9000, calls to this service will affect the emulator
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services will affect production: pubsub, storage, eventarc
firebase >
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full, actual error message.  Copy and paste it so we can see exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hi, I updated console messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are your error messages.  Read them carefully:

> params.TASKS_QUEUE_NAME.value() invoked during function deployment, instead of during runtime.
>
> This is usually a mistake. In configs, use Params directly without calling .value().
>
> example: { memory: memoryParam } not { memory: memoryParam.value() }

These messages are telling you that you should only use parameter values when your function code is running, not during deployment.  That means you should move your definition of `cloudTasksUtil` **inside your function** rather than at the global scope.

Follow the example that you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#params). Note that the parameters are defined at the global scope, and their values are only used within the function body.

```
// Define some parameters
const minInstancesConfig = defineInt('HELLO_WORLD_MININSTANCES');
const welcomeMessage = defineString('WELCOME_MESSAGE');

// To use configured parameters inside the config for a function, provide them
// directly. To use them at runtime, call .value() on them.
export const helloWorld = onRequest(
  { minInstances: minInstancesConfig },
(req, res) => {
    res.send(`${welcomeMessage.value()}! I am a function.`);
  }
);
```

Comment: If I want to have only one global instance, I should take singleton pattern, right? I thought there is some way to use StringParam in my custom class, but I missed the way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can declare the `cloudTasksUtil` variable at the global scope, but you should only initialize it in the function if it's not already.

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved this is to lazy-load the config variables into the singleton.

For example if you turn your string parameters into Function types:

```
    class CloudTasksUtil {
        constructor (
                TASKS_QUEUE_NAME:Function,
                MY_TASKS_LOCATION:Function,
                G_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL:Function,
                ProjectID:Function,
        ){
            this.TASKS_QUEUE_NAME = TASKS_QUEUE_NAME
            this.MY_TASKS_LOCATION = MY_TASKS_LOCATION
            ...
        }

        someMethodCalledLater(){
            const queueName = this.TASKS_QUEUE_NAME()
        }
```

then you can wrap each config in a closure in the functions index:

```
const cloudTasksUtil = new CloudTasksUtil(
    ()=>defineString("TASKS_QUEUE_NAME").value(),
    ()=>defineString("MY_TASKS_LOCATION").value(),
    ()=>defineString("G_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL").value(),
    ()=>projectID.value(),
)
```

which will defer the evaluation of value() until runtime when it's actually used.

I am assuming here that your CloudTasksUtil class isn't actually used during the deployment phase. I have a similar thing (a config loader with environment switches) which isn't actually used during deployment, but gets instantiated like this - instead of having to duplicate the instantiation in all the functions. I was also getting that warning during deployment, but it was not a real problem the singleton wasn't being called after being setup.