# StringParam not working in python Cloud Function Gen2 for global vars

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using the new Cloud Function gen 2 in python and following this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd) and this code sample :

```
from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_functions.params import IntParam, StringParam

MIN_INSTANCES = IntParam("HELLO_WORLD_MIN_INSTANCES")
WELCOME_MESSAGE = StringParam("WELCOME_MESSAGE")

# To use configured parameters inside the config for a function, provide them
# directly. To use them at runtime, call .value() on them.
@https_fn.on_request(min_instances=MIN_INSTANCES)
def hello_world(req):
    return https_fn.Response(f'{WELCOME_MESSAGE.value()}! I am a function!')
```

I have runtime errors because :

- First `.value()` is `str` so it's not callable, we need to use `.value`
- Second, `WELCOME_MESSAGE.value` seems to not be loaded on time for global vars

In my code :

```
db_url = StringParam("DB_URL")
db_name = StringParam("DB_NAME")


client = MongoClient(db_url.value)
db = client.get_database(db_name.value)
```

Throws an exception `pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: Empty host (or extra comma in host list)`.

The var seems to be loaded from this message : `i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.`

Note : if i `print` the value inside a function, it's working, so are parameters not available for global vars ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're having the same sort of problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76323571/807126) for nodejs, where the solution was to only request the values of parameters when the function is invoked, and not at the global scope.

I can only imagine it works the same way for python. You should consider lazy-initializing the globals after the function is invoked, if they were not already in a prior invocation.

Comment: I think i misunderstood what these parameters were. I simply want to load environment variables that should be available directly. In another project, i am using python Cloud function gen 1 without firebase, and i have a `.yaml` file for my env vars. Is it equivalent ?

Comment: I doubt it. Firebase uses different tooling and coding conventions entirely. The only thing that's the same is the underlying infrastructure and trigger behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the {Int,String}Param in the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd) for python is not working.
I can retrieve environment variable by placing `your_functions_dir/.env.{project_id}` and then in the python script:

```py
import os

MY_ENV_VAR = os.environ.get('MY_ENV_VAR')
...
```

`{project_id}` can be found at `.firebaserc`.